# Young adult book about 5 girls with superpowers

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, powers

I'm looking for a book for young adults (read it about 6 to 8 years ago, so around the 2008-2010 time frame) about 5 (or 4) girls, brought together because they have superpowers and can save the world. I read it in French, but I don't know whether it is originally written in that language.

What I remember:

- they are introduced successively, and we follow the team as it is gathered from all around the world (maybe one girl per continent? not sure). I think they all are orphans, though it might not be explicit at the beginning of the book.
- one of the girls probably comes from a country in a state of civil war
- one girl was able to speak any language **as long as she was within a certain perimeter of a speaker of the language**, which actually makes it hard for her to learn new languages in a "normal fashion".
- one girl was mute and only able to communicate via drawings, if I remember well she had precognitive abilities. (I'd say that she was from Eastern Europe, and found in an orphanage, but I'm not sure).
- at one point they are sent on a mission, to gather information. The girl who speaks languages only when at a given distance of people is given a paper which she cannot read (it is written in Russian). During the mission, the contents of the message suddenly become clear/understandable, from which she deduces that a Russian speaking person must be coming close to where she is.
- we learned at the end that they had appeared all at the same time as being "wished by the collective of humans", in a way being as unreal as Santa Claus. This collective humanity wish was brought on by the arrival of the 2000 millennium, a time which focused hopes for changes.
- I think they managed to survive at the end despite not being human/real.

Comment: Thanks for keeping on with updating this. I haven't found anything yet, but every little bit helps.

Comment: I seriously considered taking a trip to the city where I initially read it, in the hope it's still in the YA part of the local library. 
Thank you for looking :)

Comment: This draws similarities to [_The Power of Five_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Five) series by Anthony Horowitz. However, it is sufficiently different that I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: @Sensoray Nope, I don't

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot As far as I remember, it didn't include occult themes, and I'm almost certain that all the protagonists were female. The descriptiion on the wikipedia page does not ring any bell.

Comment: @C.F To be honest I didn't think it was that but it was similar enough I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @Malady - The body already mentions that the book had a French edition. I'm not sure that adding it into the header (especially if it was a translation) adds much additional value.

Comment: I read a either this or a story a lot like it years ago, involving a specific number of individuals worldwide who were born all at once as a reaction to some supernatural event, and I think matured unnaturally fast, or had no fathers, or both. Unfortunately I can't remember any more details just now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you found it after all these years, but it really sounds like ***[Le Projet Alpha](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15711395-le-projet-alpha)*** by Yvan Lallemand.

It is a French novel from 2007, with five orphan girls from all around the world, who each have a special ability and have to save the world from danger coming in the year 2000.

Translated from the French-language Goodreads synopsis:

> They are five. Nakimera, the Ugandan whose laughter charms, heals or kills. Yunhua, the Chinese girl who can learn everything instantly, and forgets likewise. Leïla, the Palestinian who understands machines and makes them obey them. Liliana, the deaf Romanian who shapes the future. Charo, the Colombian who can't lie and only hears the truth.
>
> Five teenage girls that a woman brought together to make a team, her team.
> What purpose ?
> What danger threatens the world on the horizon of the year 2000?
> What is an Aberration?
> And above all... what is Project Alpha?

Comment: Woooooow really sounds like it! I'll try to read it and confirm soon, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a book called *[The Sensitives](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35639476-the-sensitives)* by Rick Wood. It featured 
boy and girls who had a range of different abilities;

> Oscar is a loser, living with his parents, with no ambition and no
>   friends.
>
> Enter April and Julian. They, like him, are Sensitives – a person who
>   is paranormally gifted. Together they show Oscar how he could finally
>   do something amazing with his life.
>
> Then there's Kaylee. She may be ten years old, but there is nothing
>   sweet or innocent about her. She reeks of evil, with eyes of fire and
>   a smile that makes hardened police officers run with terror.
>
> As Oscar enters a full-on battle with the demon possessing this girl’s
>   body, he discovers that the use of his gift will require him to go
>   through more terror, and face more evil, than he could ever have
>   possibly imagined…

Comment: I honestly doubt it, since it was published in 2017 and there's no French translation. But always good to have related works around.

Comment: Hi, that's not the book I'm looking for, because it had no male main character, and featured 5 girls, who all were orphans. Thank you for taking the time to answer though.